# 'StarGeo' was not found on THREE.js on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I want to use a JavaScript effect that utilizes the THREE.js library in a React project. Previously, I have tested the effect in a non-React project, and it worked correctly.

The code of my effect is:

```
<script>
let scene, camera, renderer, cube;

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
}

init() {

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x2a3b4c);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 1;
camera.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
//document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


starGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
for(let i=0;i<6000;i++) {
let star = new THREE.Vector3(
Math.random() * 600 - 300,
Math.random() * 600 - 300,
Math.random() * 600 - 300
);
star.velocity = 0;
star.acceleration = 0.02;
starGeo.vertices.push(star);
}

let sprite = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'star.png' );
let starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
color: 0xaaaaaa,
size: 0.7,
map: sprite
});

stars = new THREE.Points(starGeo,starMaterial);
scene.add(stars);

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
return renderer.domElement;
}

onWindowResize() {
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
animate() {
starGeo.vertices.forEach(p => {
p.velocity += p.acceleration
p.y -= p.velocity;
if (p.y < -200) {
p.y = 200;
p.velocity = 0;
}
});
componentDidMount(); {
document.getElementById("render").appendChild(this.init());
this.animate();
}
starGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
stars.rotation.y +=0.002;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
</script>
```

Despite everything, I am still encountering the following error:

ERROR in ./src/Main/Main.jsx 30:4-11
export 'starGeo' (imported as 'starGeo') was not found in 'three'

I have installed THREE.js in React using commands, and it appears in the node modules:

npm install --save three
npm install --save-dev vite
npx vite
npm run dev

In my component, I have added the import lines:

import * as THREE from "three";

-And I have changed the syntax of my JavaScript effect to adapt to the React syntax. but it looks correct.

-Also I have added another import line where I imported 'starGeo' and other elements used by the effect, but the same error persists.

import { starGeo, stars, animate, Scene, Entity, onWindowResize, componentDidMount } from 'three';

-I have also tried exporting the specific script file that uses the 'three.min.js' effect in the main index.html of React, but it did not work."